# DateTime format in log4net AdoNetAppender

Tags: log4net

I'm using log4net and trying to pass a custom DateTime property to a database using the AdoNetAppender. I can pass in the DateTime value just fine, but the database value excludes the milliseconds. The final value is rounded to the nearest second.

I know there's the [date{} formatting](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Util.PatternString.html), but I cannot get that to work with a custom property. So, is it possible to format a custom DateTime property to include the milliseconds?

Here's my config:

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
      <bufferSize value="0" />
      <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      <connectionString value="{MyConnectionString}" />
      <commandText value="INSERT INTO MyTestLog ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception],[StartDate]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception, @start_date)" />
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_date" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@thread" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_level" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="50" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%level" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@logger" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@message" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%message" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@exception" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="2000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@start_date"/>
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{StartDate}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

My logging code is:

```
ThreadContext.Properties["StartDate"] = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10); 
log.Info("Info message w/ StartTime property");
```

The resulting value is correct (10 minutes ago), but the value is rounded to the nearest second.

I *can* get it to work if I first reformat the DateTime to a String, like this:

```
ThreadContext.Properties["StartDate"] = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz");
```

However, this seems less than optimal. Any ideas??

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**

Use `log4net.Layout.RawPropertyLayout` instead; e.g:

```
<parameter>
    <parameterName value="@start_date"/>
    <dbType value="DateTime" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawPropertyLayout">
      <key value="StartDate" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
```

---

**Option 2**

Create this (it could be a `struct` if you prefer and might reduce heap allocations depending on how you use it):

```
public class Log4NetDateTime
{
    private DateTime _value;

    public Log4NetDateTime(DateTime value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
    }
}
```

Then add `Log4NetDateTime` values instead of `DateTime` values.

---

`log4net.Layout.PatternLayout` (via `log4net.Util.PatternConverter`) just calls `ToString()` on the object, and by default this [does not include milliseconds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf(v=vs.110).aspx).